# Unique Page Titles

Tags: bigcartel

We have a custom theme which is currently pulling in the page names of each page using the BC tags.

```
<title>{{ page.name | remove: '-footer-' | remove: '-hide-' | remove: '-sidebar-' | remove: '-subnav-' | remove: '-f1-' | remove: '-f2-' | remove: '-f3-' }} | {{ store.name }}</title>
```

The trouble with this is that I wish to override each title on every page. I have one template that has the above title tag in it.

I'd like to create something like: if page is xyz url show this title, else show this title, and then repeat that for every page.

Is this possible?

Thanks kindly

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change meta page titles on Big Cartel dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842539/change-meta-page-titles-on-big-cartel-dynamically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following on a custom theme:

```
{% if page.full_path == "/category/yourcategory" %}
    <meta name="description" content="description">
    <meta name="keywords" content="keywords....">
{% elsif page.full_path == "/products" %}
    <meta name="description" content="description">
    <meta name="keywords" content="keywords....">
{% else %}
    <meta name="description" content="{{ page.meta_description }}">
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{ page.meta_keywords }}">
{% endif %}
```